# Dynamic  forms using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, software-design

I want to design and develop a web base software that enable user to report a problem or discussion using ASP.NET and SQL server.
This application might has many forms. For example Form A for reporting bug for software 1 and etc.
I don't want to create a table for keeping data per form.
Solution that comes to my mind is making UserControl per form. and when user chooses a form application loading target usercontrol.
Now I have challenge for save and restore data that user entered into target usercontrol.
What is your suggestion ?

What do you suggest instead of using UserControl ?
I have also review using XML to keeping forms structures but I think its hard to create UI from XML .

Answer (score 0):

I can not see the difficulty in saving and restoring your data.

If you use user control, then I assume you want to reuse it in other forms as well, or it doesnt make any sense.

Or what you want is to load asp.net controls dynamically?
Then step by step:

1. Firstly create a proper form page you need, then convert it into several user controls (according the business logic).
2. Reuse user controls you just converted in other forms based on XML
       config files, or URL, or query string or session. In XML you can specify the method name you going to call for saving or retrieving data. (That's the structure of one of projects I worked on)

Hoep it helps.

[How to: Convert Web Forms Pages into ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x6sx01c.aspx)